# cannot create new user in web-api 2

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm trying to create a new user when receiving a `POST` request to `api/accounts/` in my asp.net web-api 2 project.

**Attempt 1: Create `Identity User`**

I've tried exactly as it was shown in the project template:

```
// Inside Post() method
IdentityUser newUser = new IdentityUser()
{
    UserName = "username",
};
IdentityResult result = await this.UserManager.CreateAsync(newUser, "password");
```

> System.Data.Entity.Core.UpdateException: 
>   Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'Discriminator', table
>   'MyDb.dbo.AspNetUsers'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT
>   fails.\r\nThe statement has been terminated.

**Attempt 2: Create a `User`**

I've also tried adding my subclassed version of `IdentityUser`:

```
// Definition
public class User : IdentityUser
{
    public User() { }
}

// Inside Post() method
User newUser = new User()
{
    UserName = userDto.Email,
};
IdentityResult result = await this.UserManager.CreateAsync(newUser, "password");
```

> System.InvalidOperationException: 
>   Mapping and metadata information could not be found for EntityType
>   'MyProject.Data.User'.

It was working originally and I can't figure out why it isn't anymore.  Originally I added two fields onto my User object (FirstName, Lastname) but I still have the problem after removing them.

Comment: +1 I've run into a similar problem, and posted my own question regarding this. I'll be monitoring this thread. 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21661018/where-does-a-webapi-2-0-project-store-new-users-when-created-with-individual-us

Answer (score 0):

for asp identity 2.2 the column Discriminator has removed form database
you can migrate the database or simply just remove the column