# Where does a WebApi 2.0 project store new users (when created with individual user authentication)?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity

I've created a solution consisting of an MVC 5 project and a WebAPI 2.0 project, with the MVC project set to use `No authentication` settings and the WebAPI project set to use `individual users authentication` settings. I've also added a reference of my WebAPI project to my MVC project and configured the solution to use the MVC project as it's startup- the button's in the navbar take me to the views returned to me by the MVC controllers, but when visiting `/api/values` I get the XML results back, so I know my configuration is valid. My goal is to use my MVC project to only return `.cshtml` views which will in turn fetch data using JQuery ajax calls to the WebAPI and bind the returned data with `Knockout.js`.

That being said, I would like to use all the security capabilities offered by the new `Identity` API, but there's a big difference in creating a WebAPI project with IUA (individual user auth.) and creating an MVC project with IUA. When I create the WebAPI project, I get no `ApplicationUser` class deriving from `IdentityUser`, nor do my API controllers use a constructor which references an `IdentityDB` context, unlike the MVC project where it's fairly obvious how the Users will be created. 
Here's the difference in the controller code, respectively:

```
 public class AccountController : ApiController
{
    private const string LocalLoginProvider = "Local";

    public AccountController()
        : this(Startup.UserManagerFactory(), Startup.OAuthOptions.AccessTokenFormat)
    {
    }

    public AccountController(UserManager<IdentityUser> userManager,
        ISecureDataFormat<AuthenticationTicket> accessTokenFormat)
    {
        UserManager = userManager;
        AccessTokenFormat = accessTokenFormat;
    }
}...
```

..and the MVC controller:

```
public class AccountController : Controller
{
    public AccountController()
        : this(new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(new IdentityDb())))
    {
    }

    public AccountController(UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager)
    {
        UserManager = userManager;
    }

    public UserManager<ApplicationUser> UserManager { get; private set; }
}...
```

Why is there no DbContext in the `ApiController`? Where does the `UserManager` store new users when executing the `Register` method(?):

```
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Register(RegisterBindingModel model)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }

        User user = new User
        {
            UserName = model.UserName
        };

        IdentityResult result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
        IHttpActionResult errorResult = GetErrorResult(result);

        if (errorResult != null)
        {
            return errorResult;
        }

        return Ok();
    }
```

Ultimately, I would like to have my user entities reside either in my WebApi project (containing the DB access logic) or even better have a class library handle all database access. How can I obtain or create a `DbContext` instance that would work with the users created from my `ApiController` and can that context be shared to accommodate other entities related to the user? 
I realize this question is very broad and that there is no ONE RIGHT WAY to design a multi-layered application, but I feel that the users should be a "core" DB entity, equal with all others and handled by the same layer as the others, so I've decided to try and utilize the boilerplate code provided by the `Identity` API, but at the same time would like to have some flexibility and treat the users as a core entity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the same code from MVC template in WebAPI application. In your case since the WebAPI template is using IdentityUser and IdentityDbContext from the Identity Framework, the application will use the defaults and store the user information in a database using EF. The connectionstring name used by default is "DefaultConnection" so you can add a connectionstring name and specify the exact value to use.

Comment: Unknowingly, you have been most helpful! Not with this answer, per se, but I've come across this article of yours : Customizing profile information in ASP.NET Identity in VS 2013 templates. Although it deals with customizing users in an MVC project and not the WebAPI project, it has helped me immensely! I will accept you answer, and submit my own in the morning(and edit my question accordingly), just to demonstrate the result. Thank you for taking the time to read and understand my horrid post, sir!

Comment: I would just like to ask you, if you know, how does the default WebApi template (with individual user accounts), store the users? Where is the reference to an IdentityDBContext? I realize there is some subtle abstraction at work here, but even after hitting F12 on everything in sight, I still couldn't find it.

Comment: The current WebAPI template does not refer the IdentityDbContext. IdentityDbContext is defined in the Identity.EntityFramework assembly. In your WebAPI controller, when you create a user using UserManager.Create(), this call uses the IdentityDbContext from the Identity.EntityFramework. Hope this helps!!!